# creating a collection of boolean functions

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file which I wish to filter down, basically removing lines which satisfy any of a list of conditions

```
def f1(line):
    return re.search(r"condition1ToBeMet", line.strip()) is None

def f2(line):
    return re.search(r"condition2ToBeMet", line.strip()) is None

#then 
for line in file:
    if any( f1(line) or f2(line) ):
        pass #as I'm not interested in that line

    else:
        print(line)
```

In this case the "any" line is bogging me down. What's the pythonic and elegant way of solving this? My files are quite large and I can have up to ten functions I wish to run on each line so having a short-circuit such as "or" is strongly preferred

Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no need in `is True` & `== True` parts

Comment: also `re.search` never returns `bool` object: `_sre.SRE_Match` or `None` (at least in *CPython 3.5*)

Comment: In my version they actually say is None I forgot I didn't need them for True when changed it 

Got me on the second instance! Will change now. Any ideas on how to implement my function iteration? I could call all the fns and return the results to a list and place an any on that but seems expensive for the number of times I need to run this and how large my files tend to be

Comment: what about joining your regular expressions into one by alternation?

Comment: if in your original version there is check for `None`-ness, you should probably leave it in your question to be more clear, since you are skipping cases where search with any of regular expressions failed, am I right?

Comment: sometimes I want to ignore the line if the regex is true, sometimes I want to keep the line - to have the option to cycle between the search being is not None and None is necessary

Comment: please, provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), in current state it is unclear what conditions you are using and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: it's really very clear. As I've said it can change though depending on the regex as to whether it will be None or not None. It's minimal as I've just given as little info as is needed, and it's verifiable up to the extent that the working bits will work. The "any" line is the problem line I've asked for help on and that isn't verifiable as it doesn't work

Comment: `any` works with iterable of objects, you are passing single `bool` object, you can remove `any` and leave inner predicate

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Azat:

```
def f1(line):
    return re.search(r"condition1ToBeMet", line.strip()) is None

def f2(line):
    return re.search(r"condition2ToBeMet", line.strip()) is None

#then 
for line in file:
    if f1(line) or f2(line):
        pass
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, why original solution didn't work, what was wrong and what can be made to fix it, only code posts don't answer anything